# KNN query data dimension must match training data dimension

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, knn

I'm trying Bag of Words problem with a dataset which has two columns - summary and solution. I'm using KNN for it. The train dataset has 91 columns and the test dataset has 15 columns.

To generate the vectors, I'm using the following piece of code.

```
vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
train_bow_set = vectorizer.fit_transform(dataset[0]).todense()
 print( vectorizer.fit_transform(dataset[0]).todense() )
 print( vectorizer.vocabulary_ )
```

I trained it.

```
classifier = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=3)  
classifier.fit(train_bow_set, dataset[1])
```

Now, I'm testing it.

```
y_pred = classifier.predict(test_bow_set)
```

Here, I'm getting below error when I test it:

```
sklearn/neighbors/binary_tree.pxi in sklearn.neighbors.kd_tree.BinaryTree.query()
**ValueError: query data dimension must match training data dimension**
```

Comment: how did you create test_bow_set?

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are fitting the `vectorizer` on the test data again instead of using `transform` function.

Make sure you are doing the following.

```
test_bow_set = vectorizer.transform(test_dataset)
```

Comment: It's not just a guess.

Answer (score 0):

You are fitting again the vectorizer:

```
train_bow_set = vectorizer.fit_transform(dataset[0]).todense()
```

You need to keep the vectorizer *from the training* (all the preprocessing elements actually) and only use transform. Fitting again will profoundly change the results.

```
train_bow_set = vectorizer.transform(dataset[0]).todense()
```